# Deploying PHP application from GitHub on Azure failed

Tags: php, azure, cakephp, github

I am trying to deploy my PHP(CakePhp 3.2) app from GitHub on Azure as a Web app. Im using PHP 7 runtime and Composer extension. But every time i try to deploy my app I get this error:

```
Command 'starter.cmd D:\home\SiteExt ...' was aborted due to no output
nor CPU activity for 61 seconds. You can increase the
SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this
is a WebJob) if needed.\r\nstarter.cmd
D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Hooks\deploy.cmd
```

Comment: Hi, does @Alex's suggestion works on your side? Do you have any updates?

Comment: Hi, I didnt try his sugguestion because in the end I uploaded the project over ftp to Azure and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You may hit the timeout limitations that are set on the Web App level by default. You may set the [needed setting](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings) in the Web App settings for a few minutes, and it should work. You need to set SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT (see the link mentioned above). That should help.